# Runtime Error on Application.ScreenUpdating

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have code in the `Worksheet_Change` event handler, and it ends like this:

```vb
Clean:
    Set rng_advertiser = Nothing
    Set rng_campaign_name = Nothing
    Set rng_data_table = Nothing
    Set rng_placement_name = Nothing
    Set rng_apex = Nothing
    Set rng_channel = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

When the `Worksheet_Change` event handler fires, it returns `Run-time error 50290: Method ScreenUpdating of object _Application failed` - this happens on any of the methods that are placed first. I tried changed the order of the state methods but the same runtime error appears, just for the different methods i.e. `EnableEvents` etc.

I have done some digging on the web and can't find much - other then Excels ready state has been set to false. This is a read-only property so not sure how to change/ wait to ready, or even if that is the problem!

[image]

I also saw that I should fiddle around with the `Worksheet.Activate` method, and interestingly, when I place that before the `Application` methods, I get a runtime error on that!

[image]

Even weirder, is that even if I try bypass this error with `On Error Resume Next` it still returns the runtime error on the `Application` methods!

This is a new one for me, and extremely baffled, so any help with this one is much appreciated!

Comment: What stuff is running before the `Clean:` handle that could cause the `application.ready` state to be false?

Comment: `Application.Ready = false` usually means there's a form open somewhere.

Comment: @jamheadart I am not using any forms - I have just written a loop to unload all forms (even though I dont use any) and still the error occurs..

Comment: There's not much info on application.ready false, but can you think of any prior operation to the `clean` that might be freezing it? Are you switching workbooks or applications? What exactly does the rest of the ws change event do / call ? Is it connecting to a db maybe?

Comment: Just a shot is the dark: a `DoEvents` might help